# Find and Unrar all files

Tags: bash, find, exec, unrar

Hi I am working on a script that syncs content from a remote site using SFTP, then extracts any archives. However I am struggling to get the extracted files to the correct (source) directory.

I started with a for loop, but was thinking this could be more efficient.

```
list=`find $local_dir -type f -name *.rar`
for line in $list; do
DEST=${line%/*}
unrar x -o- $line $DEST
done
```

Requirements:

```
1. Find all RAR files
2. Extract all rar files to the directory each rar is located

/sync/testfile.rar --> /sync/testfile.file
/sync/testdir/testfile1.rar --> sync/testdir/testfile1.file
/sync/testdir/testfile2.rar --> sync/testdir/testfile2.file
```

Here is my current command. In the loop I used I specifically called out the destination, but am not sure how to do that here in one line.

```
find $local_dir -type f -name '*.rar' -exec unrar x -o- {} \;
```

I have also tried `unrar xe -o-` but that gives me the same result where the contents are extracted to the directory where the script was ran from.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
find $local_dir -type f -name '*.rar' -exec sh -c 'echo unrar x -o- {} $(dirname {})' \;
```

I prepended `unrar` with `echo` so that it's possible to examine what
command is going to do.  For example, for the directory structure like
this:

```
$ tree
.
├── a.rar
├── b
│   └── z.rar
└── b.rar

1 directory, 3 files
```

It would print:

```
$ find $local_dir -type f -name '*.rar' -exec sh -c 'echo unrar x -o- "{}" "$(dirname {})"' \;
unrar x -o- ./b.rar .
unrar x -o- ./a.rar .
unrar x -o- ./b/z.rar ./b
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically in your example **"-exec" should be "-execdir"** (unrar switches not tested)

Executed from the folder above sync:
folderAboveSync$ find -name '*.rar' -execdir unrar e {} \;

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html